The name of a film involving trees killing the towns people
I don’t know any of the actors and unfortunately can't describe the two main characters other then a man and woman.
Era of this film between 1980 - 90s.
I remember only some of the scenes which are listed below but not in the correct order except the last.

A woman is possibly locked in the basement she sees roots break through the wall below a window bringing bones with them.
An investigation over the murders leads to a grave being dug up and found to be filled with roots and the body gone.
A man driving, suddenly a tree tries to kill him by ramming through the windscreen, he gets away out of the car from the close encounter.
The same woman discovers the tree outside the house bleeding blood.
An old lady is drawn to the basement window then she is impaled by a root or branch.
At the end a man stands in mud and roots begin pulling him down while he or the woman is holding an axe and one of them decapitates the man or creature responsible for it all.


I'm pretty sure it's not a movie but rather an X Files episode, specifically the "Killer Trees" episode called Schizogeny (Season 5, Episode 9).

A 16-year-old boy is accused of burying his stepfather alive in the orchard mud. Later, a girl's father is also killed mysteriously near the orchard. It appears the orchard has murderous qualities. Mulder and Scully look into a connection with the two teenagers and their counselor who has a troubled past.

Every single scene you mentioned takes place there. It also ends the same. Here's the original promo, where you can briefly see the casket that's filled with roots (and the car accident):



